# increment Calendar date in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, calendar

I am writing code to add rows dynamically on selecting the month and year. It should display rows of labels with all dates for that month. 
I have written code for adding new row on button click and am stuck on *adding date  to label dynamically*

```
<BODY>                  
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" id="addRow" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />    

    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">

    </TABLE>
    <%
        int year= 2015,month = 10;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);       
        int numDays = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy"); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);      
      %>      
   <SCRIPT language="javascript">

        var count=1;
        var numDays = "<%=numDays %>"; 
        while(count <= numDays-1 ) { 
            count++;   
           // calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,count); //error in this part when uncommented

            $("#addRow").trigger("click");
        }

        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID); 
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name="chkbox[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);     
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);          
            cell2.innerHTML = "<%= df.format(calendar.getTime()) %>"; //new date here 

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2); 
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            element2.name = "txtbox[]";
            cell3.appendChild(element2); 
        }      

    </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
```

**Not able to use calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,count)** within the loop, so that date is incremented on each click. When running calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1); it is displaying output as given in image
[snapshot of output when setting DAY_OF_MONTH outside the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT6U8.jpg)

Comment: Umm `calendar` is a Java object not Javascript.  The Java code is evaluated on the server side. the Javascript is evaluated on the client side. The client has no knowledge of the Java variables whatsoever.

Comment: Is there a way to send server data to client at run time by cookie, session or other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. Actually its a other way workout.

Have fetched the no of days in the calendar (from server date) and run a loop for each count trigger the addrow button incrementing the  label value.

JS code =>

```
            numDays = "<%= numDays%>";
            while (count <= numDays - 1) {
                  count = count + 1;
                  $("#btnAddRow").trigger("click");
            }

            function addRow(tableID) {
                var countCol = parseInt($('#dataTable').attr('data-countCol'), 10) || 1;
                countRow = countRow + 1;
                var index = $("#dataTable  tr:last").attr("id").split("_")[1];
                var rid = "r_" + (parseInt(index) + 1);
                var tempRow = $("#dataTable  tr:last").clone(true, true);
                tempRow.attr("id", rid);
                var checkCol = $('#dataTable tr:last td:first input');
                checkCol.prop("check", true);
                checkCol.prop("id", "check-" + index);
                var dateCol = $('#dataTable tr:last td:nth-child(2) input');
                dateCol.prop("readonly", true);
                var pv_dt = dateCol.val().split("/");
                pv_dt[0] = parseInt(pv_dt[0]) + 1;
                var nw_dt = pv_dt.join("/");
                $(tempRow).find('td:nth-child(2) input').val(nw_dt);
                tempRow.find('td:nth-child(3) input').prop('name', "rom_" + parseInt(countRow) + "." + countCol); 
                tempRow.find('td:nth-child(4) input').prop('name', "waste_" + parseInt(countRow) + "." + countCol); 
                tempRow.find('td:nth-child(5) input').prop('name', "fh_" + parseInt(countRow) + "." + countCol); 
                tempRow.find('td:nth-child(6) input').prop('name', "ot-rom_" + parseInt(countRow) + "." + countCol); 
                tempRow.find('td:nth-child(7) input').prop('name', "ot-waste_" + parseInt(countRow) + "." + countCol); 
                tempRow.find('td:nth-child(8) input').prop('name', "ot-FH_" + parseInt(countRow) + "." + countCol); 
                $('#dataTable').append(tempRow);
            }
```